# Docker volume overwrites laravel storage permision

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker to develop a Laravel application, There is a problem couldn't figure it out yet, would be appreciate if you could help.

The storage dir needs to be writable by www-data user, which is considered in Docker file, but the way volumes are defined, overwrites permissions

```
volumes:
  - ../postapi2/:/srv/app
  - /srv/app/vendor
```

and need to chown it again when the container is up, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid overwriting the storage but still have access to it?